# How can I retrieve the target element that a jquery plugin is attached to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I am new to writing JQuery Plugins...and have a question regarding returning the selector used to bind the plugin to.

Lets say we attach a jQuery plugin to an element like this...

```
 $(".someClass").viEdit();
```

And this is the Plugin ...

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.viEdit = function () {

        var myTarget = "????"; // See Below

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Now...How can I retrieve the target that was used to bind the jQuery?

I don't mean `$(this)`, I'm looking for `.someClass` in this case.

As a second example, if it was set like this...

```
 $("#myElement").viEdit();
```

I would be looking for...

```
 #myElement
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: afaik, there's no way to reliably do that, you can pass a element to $, and that has no selector text like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.selector`:

http://jsfiddle.net/3NAwD/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.viEdit = function () {

        console.log(this.selector);

    };
}(jQuery));
```

Note that something like `$(document.getElementById('someId')).viEdit();` will give you a blank `selector`.

Comment: Ok, I see this is working, and thank you for your answer! The documentation shows this has been deprecated and removed in v1.9 yet it still seems to work. http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: I know, it doesn't make sense to me either. I wonder if there is a work around for this.

Answer (score 1):

There were a `.selector` property, which is deprecated in newer versions.

The advised method now is to pass it as a option like

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.viEdit = function (options) {

        var myTarget = options.target;

    };
}(jQuery));

$("#myElement").viEdit({
    target: '#myElement'
});
```

Comment: I see...that makes twice the work to initiate it...geez

Comment: @VIDesignz it is because we cannot always trust the value of `selector` property... assume something like `$('.myclass').filter('[myattribute]').myplugin()` then what should be the value of `selector`